# What does "Fotze" really mean?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, meaning-in-context

First of all please do not be offended by any swearing in this question, I didn't mean it.

As stated in this youtube video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dmLBk4cYP4s&t=275s (4:36)

> Fot(Fotomodell) + ze(Zeitbombe) = Fotze

And the author says it has a positive meaning. 
I've encountered however "Fotze" used as a curse e.g.

> Du Scheiß-Fotze!

But besides this obvious example containing "Scheiße".
Google translate also translates "Fotze" as "cunt" in English.

Was that guy pranked by someone with this Fot+ze explaination or has it a positive meaning is some dialects / contexts.

I would not use it either way, but you know. I'm curious. :)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirty_Hungarian_Phrasebook https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=grA5XmBRC6g

Comment: It's most likely a joke. What is the relation between a photo model and a time bomb, so why should there be an abbreviation for the combined terms?

Comment: https://www.dwds.de/wb/Fotze

Comment: @RalfFriedl Yeah probably... When I think of it right now while replaying that part of the video you're probably right. So I was pranked at some extent :)

Comment: As a newspaper journalist (in the past) I was used to use acronyms for newspapers made up from the first letters of the parts of their names. FAZ and TAZ are famous in Germany anyway. I worked for a newspaper *Schwäbische Zeitung* which the locals were used to call *SchwäZ*. Then I spent three years in Leipzig where the local newspaper is called *Leipziger Volkszeitung*. I could not get rid of the idea of reading the *Leipziger VoZe*. :-|

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The Word [Fotze](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Fotze) has the same origin as the word [Fut](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Fut), (middle high German: *vut*) and both are gross and dirty words for *vagina.* There is no other usage than as swear words. It is similar to the English words *twat* and *cunt.*

But *Fotze* is in Bavaria and Austria also a collogial term for slap in the face (synonym for *Ohrfeige*) without any sexual or dirty connotation, and in rural regions of Bavaria and Austria *Fotze* also is a dialect word for *mouth*, and so [Fotzhobel](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Fotzhobel) and [Fotzenhobel](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Fotzenhobel) are synonyms for *Mundharmonika*, i.e. a harmonica (*mouth organ*), again without any sexual or dirty connotation.  (»Der [Hobel](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Hobel)« is a fad or planer, i.e. a tool that a carpenter uses.)

The word is an old word. As said above, it already existed in German language in the 15th century, many centuries before foto models and time bombs existed. It is related to the German adjective [faul](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/faul) and also to the english adjective *foul* (rotten, stinky) and also to the German disgust expletive [pfui!](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/pfui) (*fie!* or *ugh!* in English).